# Camel XSLT message routing issue

Tags: apache-camel

I am routing a message from queue->converting it using xslt and forwarding it to another queue, log.

My Camel configuration is as follows:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    streamCache="true">
    <route>
        <from uri="jms:queue:TradeEventsToESBQueue" />
        <multicast>
            <to uri="xslt:com/tpt/esb/tradeevent/confirmation.xsl" />
            <to uri="xslt:com/tpt/esb/tradeevent/valuation.xsl" />
        </multicast>
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="xslt:com/tpt/esb/tradeevent/confirmation.xsl" />
        <to uri="log:output?showAll=true" />
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="xslt:com/tpt/esb/tradeevent/valuation.xsl" />
        <to uri="jms:queue:TradeValuationStartQueue1?jmsMessageType=Text" />
        <to uri="log:output?showAll=true" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

On running the program i get the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExpectedBodyTypeException: Could not
>   extract IN message body as type: interface javax.xml.transform.Source
>   body is: null     at
>   org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.getSource(XsltBuilder.java:482)[64:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.1]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.process(XsltBuilder.java:125)[64:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.1]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorPollingConsumer.receive(ProcessorPollingConsumer.java:58)[64:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.1]

Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the XSLT component in that manner.

You should particularly not try to use "from" with XSLT, but rather use it in combination with any internal transport component (directly for the instance). I think the following will do what you want.

```
<route>
    <from uri="jms:queue:TradeEventsToESBQueue" />
    <multicast>
        <to uri="direct:confirmation"/>
        <to uri="direct:valuation"/>
    </multicast>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="direct:confirmation"/>
  <to uri="xslt:com/tpt/esb/tradeevent/confirmation.xsl" />
  <to uri="log:output?showAll=true" />
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="direct:valuation"/>
  <to uri="xslt:com/tpt/esb/tradeevent/valuation.xsl" />
  <to uri="jms:queue:TradeValuationStartQueue1?jmsMessageType=Text" />
  <to uri="log:output?showAll=true" />
</route>
```